# Let $f:[0,2)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ restricted to $(1,2)$ is Lipschitz. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous?

Tags: analysis, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $f:[0,2)\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous such that $f$ restricted to $(1,2)$ is Lipschitz. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

I know that as $f:(1,2)\to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz, it is uniformly continuous. But why does $f:(1,2)\to \mathbb{R}$ being Lipschitz forces $f:[0,2)\to \mathbb{R}$ to be uniformly continuous?

Comment: Do you know anything more about $f$ on $[0,1)$? As it is stated $f$ does not even need to be continuous on $[0,1)$. Just imagine a jump there.

Comment: To ensure the uniform continuity of $f$ on all of $[0,2)$, you have to tame the behavior of $f(x)$ as $x\to2^-$. Lipschitz continuity of $f$ near $x=2$ will ensure this.

Comment: It's not true. Take $f$ to be identity function on $(1,2)$ and let $f(x)=\frac 12$ on $[0,1]$ then $f$ is not even continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: Please update your question to stipulate that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Sorry, guys. I messed up, the question is corrected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need are these three facts:

1. a continuous function on a compact set is [uniformly continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem);
2. all Lipschitz functions are [uniformly continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Examples_and_counterexamples);
3. if a function is uniformly continuous on $A$ and $B$, and continuous on $A\cup B$, then it is uniformly continuous on $A\cup B$.

Now take $A=[0,\frac32]$ and $B=(1,2)$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $A=[0,1]$?

Comment: @RedBanana: You could take $A=[0,1]$, but then you have to point out that $f$ is continuous at $1$. Not a problem, but I took $A=[0,\frac32]$ so I wouldn't have to. (But I ended up having to point it out anyway. Oh well.)

Answer (score 1):

In general I dont think that this statement is true. One could for example take the following map:
$$f:[0,2)\to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto \begin{cases} 
1 & x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1] \\
0 & x\in (\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}) \cap [0,1] \\
x & x\in (1,2)
\end{cases}$$
then this map is Lipschitz-continous on $[1,2)$ however not (unif.) continous on $[0,2)$.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. The question is corrected now.